# shorten multiple ID on div with shorter jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to achieve this :

i have 30 white circles. each white circle will trigger a popup to new image option, whatever it's gold or silver.

when i click on gold, the previously clicked circle will turn to gold while the other 29 remain white.
when that gold circle clicked again, i can choose silver and it will turn to silver while the other remains white.

how to do this without giving 30 id's / classes to each circle ?

thanks

here is my codes (only give 4 circle for example) :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".circle").click(function(){
        $(".silver , .gold").toggle();
    });

});
```

```css
.circle{
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: solid 1px black;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 background: none;
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.silver,
.gold{
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="silver" onclick="addsilver();"><img src="images/silver.png" width="40"></div>
    <div class="silver" onclick="addgold();"><img src="images/silver.png" width="40"></div>

    <div class="circle" id="c1"></div>
    <div class="circle" id="c2"></div>
    <div class="circle" id="c3"></div>
    <div class="circle" id="c4"></div>
    <div class="circle" id="c5"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see the code snippet to understand the solution

```js
var currentCircleId = '';

$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $(".circle").click(function(){
        $(".selection").toggle();
        currentCircleId = $(this).attr('id');
    });
    $('.selection').click(function(){
        $(".selection").toggle();
        var newClass = $(this).data('new-class');
        $('#' + currentCircleId).removeClass('gold silver').addClass(newClass);
    });
    

});
```

```css
.circle{
 border-radius: 50%;
 border: solid 1px black;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 background: none;
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
}
.silver {
   background-color: silver; 
}
.gold{
 background-color: yellow;
}
.selection {
    display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="selection" data-new-class="gold">Gold</div>
<div class="selection" data-new-class="silver">Silver</div>

    <div class="circle" id="c1"></div>
    <div class="circle" id="c2"></div>
    <div class="circle" id="c3"></div>
    <div class="circle" id="c4"></div>
    <div class="circle" id="c5"></div>
```

Comment: if this code is helpful for you, please give me credit :)

Comment: this only works one way, how to redo the previously silver ?

Comment: for example, silver silver silver silver, want change to gold silver silver silver

Comment: just remove all previous classes and add new class :)